# Унарный и бинарный операторы проверки на равенство

Tags: c++, операторы

Подскажите, почему оператор проверки на равенство может быть как членом  класса (унарным), так и внешним (бинарным)?

```
bool T::operator==(const T& t);
bool operator==(const T& t1, const T& t2);
```

Comment: А почему функция с любым именем может быть как членом класса, так и свободной функцией (с одним дополнительным аргументом)? Например `bool T::f(T&x)` и `bool f(T&x, T&y)`? Это же вас не удивляет? А ситуация ровно та же...

Comment: @Harry, я просто хочу понять, действительно ли в некоторых случаях один вариант дает преимущество над другим. И что это за случаи - тоже хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Они оба бинарные.

Comment: @user7860670, я имел в виду вариативность: один и два параметра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, например...

```
bool T::operator==(const T& a);
```

и

```
T::T(int);
```

Вы никак не сможете выполнить проверку

```
T t;
if (5 == t)
```

в то время как для случая свободного оператора - запросто, благодаря приведению типа...

Вот живой пример:

```
struct T
{
    int i;

    T(int i):i(i){}
    bool operator==(const T& t) { return t.i == i; }
};

// bool operator==(const T& t, const T& u) { return t.i == u.i; }


int main()
{
    T t(5);
    cout << (4 == t);
}
```

Попробуйте скомпилировать - ничего не выйдет. Но уберите комментарий - и все заработает.

Так понятно?

Оператор как член класса требует, чтобы первым аргументом был однозначно объект этого класса, без каких-либо приведений типа etc.

Comment: Понял, большое вам спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор сравнения, определенный вне класса, определяет общее правило  сравнения для всех его экземпляров и экземпляров производных классов.  Если  имеем:

```
struct MyCont {  
   //...        
    bool operator ==(const MyCont& v)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

То, `operator ==` предназначен, чтобы сравнить обьекты `MyCont`(левый операнд оператора) с обьектами этого типа или производными типами, так, что `MyCont&` могла ссылаться на них(правый операнд оператора). Теперь напишем производный тип и  напишем для него свой оператор:

```
//сравнивается не так, как MyCont
struct MyVector : public MyCont {
    //...        
    bool operator ==(const MyVector& v)
    {
        //...
    }
};
//и создадим экземпляры 
MyCont base(5);
MyVector v1(4), v2(4);
```

Для  `MyVector::operator==` действуют те же правила, поэтому мы можем  сравнивать так:

```
base == v1; // правильно: MyCont::operator==
base == v2; 
v1 == v2;   //правильно:  MyVector::operator==
```

Но не сможем выполнить сравнение `v1 == base` или `v2 == base`,  потому что справа обьект не того же типа или производнего от него типа. Но если определим свободный оператор:

```
bool operator ==(const MyCont& v1, const MyCont& v2)
{
   //...
}
```

То этот оператор определит общее правило сравнения для всех типов, которые неявно могут преобразоваться в `MyCont`, поэтому можем без проблем выполнить: `v1 == base` или `v2 == base`, и, может быть, какие то операторы, определенные в классах окажутся не нужными, и можно будет убрать их с интерфейса(разгрузить интерфейс).

Есть еще причина, которая делает целесообразным определение оператора вне класса. Допустим есть **класс коробок** и **класс продуктов**, которые нужно складывать в коробки.

1. Для класса **Коробка** существенны его  размеры, их всегда выбирают
   по размерам, поэтому целесообразно в нем иметь `operator==` (это
   имеет прямое отношение к его абстракции).
2. А вот продукты могут быть такие, что для них важны многие
   характеристики, но клиентам не нужно их проверять на равенство,
   поэтому при абстрагировании нам `operator==` становится как бы
   избыточным.  Но для тех, кто контролирует качество содержимого  в
   ящиках(какой продукт в какой ящик должен попадать), должно
   существовать правило сравнения, поэтому для них отдельно пишется это
   правило. Таким образом `operator==` становится определенным вне
   класса, из за логических сооброжений.